# How to get Complete QueryString?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get complete querystring in asp.net?
Suppose a QueryString like this passed to my Login Page.

```
login.aspx?redirect=cart.aspx&p=1&q=2&r=3
```

I have to pass parameters p,q and r to Cart.aspx with all of the parameters except redirect.
Login.aspx may handle different querystrings but all parameters except the redirect are to be passed to the redirecting page.(Actually, I know there will be a parameter 'redirect' but can't write code for p,q,and r bcoz it may change in different contexts)

***The parameters except 'redirect' will be different in different contexts. The p,q,r are required parameters for cart.aspx. If the redirection is to another page then the parameters may not be p,q,r instead something else like l,m,n***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this

```
Request.Url.Query
```

Input like this

```
Input: http://localhost:96/Cambia3/Temp/Test.aspx?q=item#fragment
```

Output

Comment: Oh thanks! atlast you got  my problem! wasn't my question clear?

Comment: You are welcome. It was clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the parameters using

```
string _url=Request.RawUrl.toString();

and

For path ... 

string _path = Request.Path.ToString();


string _url = Request.ServerVariables["URL"].ToString();

O/P = /Home/About/
```

RawURl Returns whole querystring....